# What does this say in the picture ( insert below)?

Tags: translation

[image]

Hello just wanted to know what this means on the phone. Didn't want to walking around not knowing what the characters mean and have it be insensitive.

Comment: What I found interesting is that while 初がつお is Japanese, 喵 at the bottom right is Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

初がつお= the first bonito, the firstly-taken bonito of the year

初＝the first, for the first time

かつお＝bonito (fish)

Some people who like something new would like to get and eat "初がつお," just like they would like to get and drink "Beaujolais nouveau."

"The first bonito" would be a symbol of something happy, or new, or a good fortune.